# How to click on the first result on a dynamic page using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, click, dynamic-pages

I am trying to click on the first result on [this](https://www.redfin.com/myredfin/favorites) page, but all the options I tried didn't work.

Firstly I just login into the website with email: kocianlukyluk@gmail.com and password: Redfinpython06. Here is the code for it:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\kocia\\OneDrive\\Plocha\\Python\\nastaveni\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/myredfin/favorites')

email = 'kocianlukyluk@gmail.com'
password = 'Redfinpython06'

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="content"]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/span[1]/span/div/input').send_keys(email)

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="content"]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/span[2]/span/div/input').send_keys(password)

time.sleep(3)
sing_up = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]')
sing_up.click()
```

But the **problem is** after login **i can't click on the first result** on the page.

Here is what i tried:

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="content"]/div[10]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div")[0]
result.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="content"]/div[10]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]").click()
```

or

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="content"]/div[10]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div")[0]
result.click()
```

or

```
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="content"]/div[10]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]")
result.click()
```

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that is a dummy email and password that you are just using for testing purposes :)

Below clicks on the first house picture in the list.   I also cleaned up your `email` and `password` xpath designations. You can see how much easier it is to grab them by `name`

Also, you may want to put proper wait methods around these find elements.  Using `sleep` generally is not recommended

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/myredfin/favorites')

email = 'kocianlukyluk@gmail.com'
password = 'Redfinpython06'

sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_name(
    'emailInput').send_keys(email)

sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_name(
    'passwordInput').send_keys(password)

sleep(3)
sing_up = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]')
sing_up.click()
sleep(3)

first_house = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='FavoritesHome'][1]//img")
first_house.click()
```